# Why does my Select device activity not run?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have been making an App through android studio. The Idea of the app is that it takes data from arduino through bluetooth and shows that data to the user.
But The Java Class that I have Made for the Select device activity which is the one that starts it all does not run. I have checked this using logcat. `
I have also posted all of my code on github: https://github.com/OtakuDisease/Hivey
This is the SelectDeviceActivity.java class.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.hivey.ui.DeviceInfoModel;
import com.example.hivey.ui.DeviceListAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SelectDeviceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_device);
        // Bluetooth Setup
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get List of Paired Bluetooth Device
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        List<Object> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                DeviceInfoModel deviceInfoModel = new DeviceInfoModel(deviceName,deviceHardwareAddress);
                deviceList.add(deviceInfoModel);
            }
            // Display paired device using recyclerView
            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDevice);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            DeviceListAdapter deviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(this,deviceList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        } else {
            View view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDevice);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Activate Bluetooth or pair a Bluetooth device", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }
            });
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you send you logcat error please ?
It's maybe a null pointer exception (maybe, not sur)

Comment: Well that is the thing.... Logcat does not show an error.